# What does Transform::linear() return in the Eigen library?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigen

With the `Eigen` C++ library, I'm having trouble understanding the `Transform::linear()` function. According to the documentation, it returns `the linear part of the transformation`. But what does this mean? Surely all matrix transformations are linear?

Furthermore, from seeing some examples elsewhere, it seems that the value it returns is an `Eigen::Matrix3d` (or can be implicitly converted to this). To me, this suggests that it might be returning just the rotation part of the transformation, which is of length 3 (x, y and z). However, there is also a `Transform::rotation()` function, which according to the documentation returns `the rotation part of the transformation`.

So can somebody explain to me what `Transform::linear()` actually returns?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The class `Transform` represents either an affine or a projective transformation using homogenous calculus. For instance, an affine transformation `A` is composed of a linear part `L` and a translation `t` such that transforming a point `p` by `A` is equivalent to:

```
 p' = L * p + t
```

Using homogeneous vectors:

```
 [p'] = [L t] * [p] = A * [p]
 [1 ]   [0 1]   [1]       [1]
```

with:

```
 A = [L t]
     [0 1]
```

So the linear part correspond to the top-left corner of the homogenous matrix representation. It corresponds to a mix of rotation, scaling and shearing.

Comment: Do you mean the `top-left` corner of the homogenous matrix?

Answer (score 17):

Having come across the same question, I would like to add the following information:

As explained by @ggael, `Transform::linear()` directly returns the linear part in the transformation matrix.

`Transform::rotation()` returns the rotational component *in the linear part*. But since the linear part contains [not only rotation but also reflection, shear and scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Image_transformation), extracting the rotation isn't straight forward, and needs to be calculated using a singular value decomposition (SVD).

In the common case where the **affine matrix is known to contain only rotation and translation** then `Transform::linear()` can be used to efficiently access the rotation part.

Finally, if you set the `Transform`'s `Mode` template parameter to `Isometry`, Eigen will assume only rotations and translations, and optimize calculation of the inverse transform. The latest versions of Eigen will also optimize `Transform::rotation()` in that case, and directly return the linear part. Note, however, that there isn't a compact version of isometric affine matrices, where the last row isn't stored and assumed to be [0 ... 0 1].

Comment: As someone uses rotation and translation only I found this answer better. Thanks.

Comment: Where can I find documentation on the `rotation()` automatic optimization? I haven't found anything in Eigen docs or changelog...